# How to access flickr user id from username search API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flickr

I am working on a small app to access the flickr api and serve up photos.  I am using the flickr gem for auth. It is working for recent photos, which are displayed if nothing is entered in the form yet.  It is working for search by tags.  It was working by user_id, but I am trying to change it to accept username, and then use the flickr.people.findByUsername method to get the user id and then use that to pull up the photos.  It's easy to find peoples usernames on the flickr website, but hard to find ID's so I think this will be more user friendly.  Here's the current version of the app before I branched it to attempt this.  https://flickr-photo-feed.herokuapp.com/ It's a very basic app with no model and no database.  There is only the index controller action and a very basic form partial and another partial to render the returned photos.

I changed the form to accept username

```rb
<div class="form">
  <%= form_with url: :root, method: :get do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username", class: "form-field" %>
    <%= form.text_field :tags, placeholder: "tags", class: "form-field" %>
    <%= form.submit 'submit', class: "submit-btn" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  require "flickr"

  def index
    @flickr = Flickr.new
    if params[:username].present?
      user_id = @flickr.people.findByUsername username: params[:username]
      @photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id
    elsif params[:tags].present?
      @photos = @flickr.photos.search tags: params[:tags], safesearch: 1
    else
      @photos = @flickr.photos.getRecent
    end
  end
end
```

If I enter a username, I get this error:

> undefined method `delete' for {"id"=>"132822455@N05","nsid"=>"132822455@N05",
> "username"=>"images@twiston"}:Flickr::Response Extracted source
> (around line #8): 6 7 8 9 10 11
>
> ```
> if params[:username].present?
>   user_id = @flickr.people.findByUsername username: params[:username]
>   @photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id
> elsif params[:tags].present?
>   @photos = @flickr.photos.search tags: params[:tags], safesearch: 1
> else
> ```

with this error in the rails server:

> oauth_args = args.delete(:oauth) || {}

As you can see, I'm getting a response with the nsid in it.  I don't quite understand the no method error for delete, but I gather that it is coming from the flickr gem.  So, I figure that I need pull the nsid out of the hash and pass it to my api call.  So, I change one line to be:

```rb
      @photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id["nsid"]
```

which generates this error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

So, I try this:

```rb
      @photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id[:nsid]
```

which gives me this error:

> undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

I even tried this:

```rb
      @photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id.nsid
```

which gets me this error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

I have tried a few other things as well, but the result is always one of those error messages.  can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?  Thank you.

Edit:  I've been able to verify that I can puts the user_id["nsid"] and the correct nsid is output to the rails server.  However, I still get the "no implicit conversion of symbol to string" error.  So, I tried saving it to a variable and explicitly calling .to_str on it before passing it to the @flickr.people.getPhotos method.  I have verified with p (not puts) that it does get output as a string. The ""show up around it.  However, that particular error persists.

Edit to add the initializers/flickr.rb file:

```rb
require "dotenv/load"
require "flickr"

flickr_api_key = ENV["FLICKR_API_KEY"]
flickr_shared_secret = ENV["FLICKR_SHARED_SECRET"]
flickr = Flickr.new flickr_api_key, flickr_shared_secret

# This is the URL Flickr will redirect your users to once they agree to access
@callback_url = "http://localhost:3000/auth_controller/callback"

# Users should hit this method to get the link which sends them to flickr
def auth
  flickr = Flickr.new API_KEY, SHARED_SECRET
  token = flickr.get_request_token(oauth_callback: URI.escape(@callback_url))
  # You'll need to store the token somewhere for when the user is returned to the callback method
  # I stick mine in memcache with their session key as the cache key

  @auth_url = flickr.get_authorize_url(token["oauth_token"], perms: "delete")
  # Stick @auth_url in your template for users to click
end

# Your users browser will be redirected here from Flickr (see @callback_url above)
def callback
  flickr = Flickr.new

  request_token = # Retrieve from cache or session etc - see above
    oauth_token = params[:oauth_token]
  oauth_verifier = params[:oauth_verifier]

  raw_token =
    flickr.get_access_token(
      request_token["oauth_token"],
      request_token["oauth_token_secret"],
      oauth_verifier
    )
  # raw_token is a hash like this {"user_nsid"=>"92023420%40N00", "oauth_token_secret"=>"XXXXXX", "username"=>"boncey", "fullname"=>"Darren%20Greaves", "oauth_token"=>"XXXXXX"}
  # Use URI.unescape on the nsid and name parameters

  oauth_token = raw_token["oauth_token"]
  oauth_token_secret = raw_token["oauth_token_secret"]

  # Store the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret in session or database
  #   and attach to a Flickr instance before calling any methods requiring authentication

  # Attach the tokens to your flickr instance - you can now make authenticated calls with the flickr object
  flickr.access_token = oauth_token
  flickr.access_secret = oauth_token_secret
end
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for `.findByUsername`? I don't see it anywhere in the gem code on github.

Comment: It's on the flickr API docs.  The gem just handles auth (I think) and allows you to use the flickr API methods.  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.findByUsername.html.

Comment: Looking at the payload using their API explorer I see  `method=flickr.people.findByUsername&magic_cookie=234b3965a506258b27e290d9884390067ae509406db656daa6ba05d0f81124b7&param_api_key=&enable_username=on&param_username=images%40twiston&format=json-nc&sign_call=full`

Comment: Using their API explorer I see the query params as:
`method: flickr.people.findByUsername
magic_cookie: 234b3965a506258b27e290d9884390067ae509406db656daa6ba05d0f81124b7
param_api_key: 
enable_username: on
param_username: images%40twiston
format: json-nc
sign_call: full`

Comment: Not sure about `enable_username: on` but it looks like it should be `param_username: images%40twiston`. When using your new code does the payload automatically translate `username` to `param_username` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not great, but it looks like it should be:

```
 flickr = Flickr.new "api key", "api secret"
 @user = flickr.people.findByUsername username: 'images@twiston'
 #=> {"id"=>"132822455@N05", "nsid"=>"132822455@N05", "username"=>"images@twiston"}
```

Which give you:

```
@user['nsid']
#=> "132822455@N05"
@user['id']
#=> "132822455@N05"
```

So your code should be something like:

```
 @user = @flickr.people.findByUsername username: params[:username]
 @photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id: @user['id']
```

The `findByUsername` method returns that hash and you were treating it as if it returns just the :id.

The docs say:
Alternatively, if the API key and Shared Secret are not provided, Flickr will attempt to read them from environment variables:

ENV['FLICKR_API_KEY']

ENV['FLICKR_SHARED_SECRET']

You could use the console to do a manual authentication with the key and secret per my example to make sure it's working right.

Comment: Oauth is handled by a flickr.rb file in initializers, so when the app starts, auth gets taken care of.  The app works fine in its initial form where It was search by user_id or tags.  I will try using an instance variable vs a local variable as you have done.  Thank you very much for taking a look at this.  That's basically the only code that I hadn't shared.  I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: The problem isn't the instance vs local variable. It's that you were getting back a response object that is accessed in hash form. If the response object was just `{user_id: 'xxxxx'}` then it would work in your original form because the method `.people.getPhotos` is accepting a hash. But the user lookup returns a hash with three key/value pairs so you have to specify which one to use.

Comment: Another weird thing I found: I tried to look up my own account via username and it says not found. But I can look myself up by email or id, and the response shows my username, but it still refuses to find me by name. I have a very old account that got merged with my yahoo account.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  I couldn't figure why an instance variable would make a difference.  If you look at my edit from earlier, you will see that I'm now specifying ['nsid"] and am able to use p to output that as a string to rails server output.  Basically I'm getting what I want back in the response and I'm able to access that, but I'm not able to properly send that in the request for photos by user_id.

Comment: It looks like you are still doing:  `@photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id["nsid"]` ? You need to pass a hash to the method: `@photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id: user_id["nsid"]`

Comment: I think you might have just cracked it.  I will try that in the morning and will be sure to let you know how it goes.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate you looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
response = @flickr.people.findByUsername username: params[:username]
@photos = @flickr.people.getPhotos user_id: response["nsid"]
```

Beartech was correct.  This worked right away.

Comment: If my answer was correct can you hit the "accept" button to accept it as the answer?  That's the usual practice rather than adding an answer that repeats the solution.